# Whey protein intake and side effects

Tags: protein, low-carb

I havent taken any whey protein, but now im planning to try and i just need to be clear with the instruction on how should i consume them.

I have several questions regarding with whey protein intake.

```
 1. How often do i need to take whey protein?
 2. How many scoops/grams per day?
 3. If i take whey protein everyday will it cause anything with my
    kidney?
 4. Is taking whey protein good for getting cuts?
 5. Is whey protein + oats good?
 6. is it good if i just eat just oats for every meal of the day?
```

thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: How are your questions related to fitness?

Comment: fitness - "the condition of being physically fit and healthy."

Comment: Your questions are straight nutrition, which is off topic for the site.

Answer (score 1):

6: No, it it is not good if you eat oats every meal of the day.

"Whey" protein is nothing magical. It's just a particular food that has a rather decent nutritional profile and there happens to be a ton of the stuff because of dairy production overall.

Ballpark you should shoot for 1 gram or so per pound of body weight. Some folks say half as much, some people double it. Most calculations you'll hear are per pound of *lean* body weight, which is less than your normal body weight.

You should have enough protein in your diet every day. I'm not aware of any evidence that says you need to have more at the end of a workout in particular. Your muscles get repaired over multiple days, little by little.

And just to throw this out there, there's a lot more to a healthy diet than simply your macros. Fresh plants and nutrients from other sources are also required to patch your muscles up.

Comment: what plants/vegetables would you recommend? the thing is im not very much of a vegetable eater.

Comment: Salads are easy: just get a premixed one, add some grilled chicken, and use some olive oil and vinegar (red wine or balsamic) dressing. You can drizzle some oil on broccoli and bake it for 30 minutes, and do the same for carrots. Kale chips can work too if you dig the flavor. Spaghetti squash and sweet potatoes are kick ass as well.